# speech_recognition sem valor

Tags: python

Eu fiz um programa para abrir aplicativos de uma pasta, e nesse caso funciona perfeitamente, o problema é que ele dá erro se eu não falar nada, sendo que o meu objetivo era deixar o programa executando em segundo plano

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os

while True:
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()
    with mic as source:
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
    output = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
    print(output)
    if 'break' in output:
        break
    elif 'open' in output:
        app = output.replace('open ', '')
        print(app)
        os.startfile(f"C:\AtalhosFaim\{app}")

        print('Nada')
    print(output)
print('Fim')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que tratar o erro de Timeout\ UnknownValueError\ RequestError:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os

while True:
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()
    with mic as source:
        print('# ouvindo.')
        audio = recognizer.listen(source, timeout = None)

    try:
        output = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
        print(output)
        
        if 'break' in output:
            break
        elif 'open' in output:
            app = output.replace('open ', '')
            print(app)
            os.startfile(f"C:\AtalhosFaim\{app}")
            
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        pass
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        pass
```

Utilizando esse bloco try você consegue manter seu código rodando.